# Jvector Map how to display database value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jvectormap

I have created Jvector Map. its working fine well.i did many customization in jvector map.change hover function to click function.finally i  want display country details display from databse. i have created simple database in particular two country india and canada.
Here My database query:

```
'1', 'canada', 'North America', 'None', 'Giovanni Facciponte', 'Approved'
 '2', 'India', 'ROW', 'None', 'Ritika Balaji', 'Require Approvel'
```

Here  paste My php database code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

$_country = $_GET['country'];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT countryId,country,pdogcoregion,ccl,category FROM countrydetails WHERE country='".$_country."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "country: " . $row["country"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

ajax script php file :

```
 <

script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function(){
          var $ = jQuery;
          $('#focus-single').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-init').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
          });
          $('#map1').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            panOnDrag: true,
            focusOn: {
              x: 0.5,
              y: 0.5,
              scale: 1,
              animate: true
            },
            series: {
              regions: [{
                scale: ['#688FA0'],
                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
                values: {
     }]
            },
            onRegionClick: function (event, data) {
            var map = $('#map1').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
            var name = map.getRegionName(data);
            // get from DB using ajax

        $(document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'database.php',
        data: {country: name},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);

        }
    });
```

Its working two country my database showing alert only.when i click canada country its showing country name from jvector file.how to set database value  both india and canda country ?

here post my screenshoot:
  [image]

alert box value from database? another value click value showing from jvector file ? how to set  database value for particular country?